# Observable.Range being repeated?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

New to Rx -- I have a sequence that appears to be functioning correctly except for the fact that it appears to repeat.

I think I'm missing something around calls to `Select()` or `SelectMany()` that triggers the range to re-evaluate.

#### Explanation of Code & What I'm trying to Do

- For all numbers, loop through a method that retrieves data (paged from a database).
- Eventually, this data will be empty (I only want to keep processing while it retrieves data
- For each of those records retrieved, I only want to process ones that should be processed
- Of those that should be processed, I'd like to process up to `x` of them in parallel (according to a setting).
- I want to wait until the entire sequence is completed to exit the method (hence the wait call at the end).

#### Problem With the Code Below

- I run the code through with a data set that I know only has 1 item.

  - So, page 0 returns 1 item, and page 1 return 0 items.
- My expectation is that the process runs once for the one item.
- However, I see that both page 0 and 1 are called twice and the process thus runs twice.

I think this has something to do with a call that is causing the range to re-evaluate beginning from 0, but I can't figure out what that it is.

#### The Code

```
var query = Observable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    .Select(pageNum =>
        {
            _etlLogger.Info("Calling GetResProfIDsToProcess with pageNum of {0}", pageNum);
            return _recordsToProcessRetriever.GetResProfIDsToProcess(pageNum, _processorSettings.BatchSize);
        })
    .TakeWhile(resProfList => resProfList.Any())
    .SelectMany(records => records.Where(x=> _determiner.ShouldProcess(x)))
    .Select(resProf => Observable.Start(async () => await _schoolDataProcessor.ProcessSchoolsAsync(resProf)))
    .Merge(maxConcurrent: _processorSettings.ParallelProperties)
    .Do(async trackingRequests =>
    {
        await CreateRequests(trackingRequests.Result, createTrackingPayload);

        var numberOfAttachments = SumOfRequestType(trackingRequests.Result, TrackingRecordRequestType.AttachSchool);
        var numberOfDetachments = SumOfRequestType(trackingRequests.Result, TrackingRecordRequestType.DetachSchool);
        var numberOfAssignmentTypeUpdates = SumOfRequestType(trackingRequests.Result,
            TrackingRecordRequestType.UpdateAssignmentType);

        _etlLogger.Info("Extractor generated {0} attachments, {1} detachments, and {2} assignment type changes.",
            numberOfAttachments, numberOfDetachments, numberOfAssignmentTypeUpdates);
    });

var subscription = query.Subscribe(
trackingRequests =>
{
    //Nothing really needs to happen here. Technically we're just doing something when it's done.
},
() =>
{
    _etlLogger.Info("Finished! Woohoo!");
});

await query.Wait();
```

Comment: I'm 90% sure you evaluate both at `query.Subscribe(...)` and `query.Wait()`.

Comment: @Dorus ahhh, that definitely could be it. I'll dig into that aspect; thanks

Comment: @Dorus also, do you know any way to combine both operations? My goal is to wait until all the operations are completed before exiting this method (due to limitations of a framework I'm working within).

Comment: I just realize: Since your subscription logic is empty (everything happens in the preceding `Do`), you can also remove the `Subscribe` line and put the code from `onComplete` right after the wait. `var query = Observable.Range [...] ; await connectable.LastOrDefaultAsync(); _etlLogger.Info("Finished! Woohoo!");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you subscribe to the sequence twice. Once at `query.Subscribe(...)` and again at `query.Wait()`.

`Observable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)` is a cold observable. Every time you subscribe to it, it will be evaluated again. You could make the observable hot by publishing it with `Publish()`, then subscribe to it, and then `Connect()` and then `Wait()`. This does add a risk to get a `InvalidOperationException` if you call `Wait()` after the last element is already yielded. A better alternative is `LastOrDefaultAsync()`.

That would get you something like this:

```
var connectable = query.Publish();
var subscription = connectable.Subscribe(...);
subscription = new CompositeDisposable(connectable.Connect(), subscription);
await connectable.LastOrDefaultAsync();
```

Or you can avoid await and return a task directly with `ToTask()` (do remove async from your method signature).

```
return connectable.LastOrDefaultAsync().ToTask();
```

Once converted to a task, you can synchronously wait for it with `Wait()` (do not confuse `Task.Wait()` with `Observable.Wait()`).

```
connectable.LastOrDefaultAsync().ToTask().Wait();
```

However, most likely you do not want to wait at all! Waiting in a async context makes little sense. What you should do it put the remaining of the code that needs to run after the sequence completes in the `OnComplete()` part of the subscription. If you have (clean-up) code that needs to run even when you unsubscribe (Dispose), consider `Observable.Using` or the `Finally(...)` method to ensure this code is ran.

Comment: Great answer! Makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately I do actually need to wait in this context (and I recognize that it's not recommended behavior). Once the async method I'm operating on completes, the framework I'm operating in changes a status and begins to process items. So, if I exit before those items have been added by my async process, they are never processed at all. Stuck with it for now.

Comment: It definitely sounds like it's onto something. Could you help me understand in what ways my code could be modified to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like @Dorus is right. Also it seems odd to get a set of data and not process any of it until you have all of it. This is sort against the spirit of working with Rx. Just process the data as you get it.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the cause of the `Observable.Range` being repeated is the fact that you're subscribing twice - once with `.Subscribe(...)` and once with `.Wait()`.

In this kind of circumstance I would go with a very simple blocking call to get the values. Just do this:

```
var results = query.ToArray().Wait();
```

The `.ToArray()` turns a multi-valued `IObservable<T>` into a single values `IObservable<T[]>`. The `.Wait()` turns this into `T[]`. It's the easy way to ensure only one subscription, blocking, and getting all of the values out.

In your case you may not need all values, but I think this is a good habit to get into.